# ASP.NET Web API2: Rendering an index.HTML for catch-all routes

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have two C# projects created in Visual Studio:

- MyApp.FrontEnd (an AngularJS app)
- MyApp.WebApi (an ASP.NET Web Api2 project)

Here's the structure of MyApp.FrontEnd

- app

  - vendor (contains third party JS libraries)
- index.html

I want to create a catch-all route inside WebApiConfig.cs under MyApp.WebApi that returns index.html.
I don't know how to return that file, as it is inside another project. Is there any other way to do?

**EDIT**
I also foresee CORS issue if the file is requested from another project. Just an FYI, Both projects will be hosted in IIS.

Comment: It is not obvious to me, but why you would _ever_ want to do this? That completely defeats the purpose of your project setup.

Comment: index.html page is the starting page of my angularjs application, which is inside MyApp.FrontEnd. I want angularjs to handle the routing rather than web api to handle it. Thats the reason I want to introduce catch-all route inside web api so that it can return the index.html file. For example, if the user refreshes the page by pressing CTRL+F5, I want to return the index page and let AngularJS deal with the routing.

Comment: Angular has it's own routing. You configure it to call the controller actions of your WebAPI project. Are you not using `angular-route.js`? Your WebAPI project connects to your database and preforms CRUD operations on your data right?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, by saying - "angularjs to handle the routing", I meant using angular-route. So yes I am using angular-route. But i want angular-route to manage all the routing for me, and the only routing I want  the WebApi to handle is the catch-all route. Does that make sense to you? Or you have any other alternative

Comment: It seems to me that you shouldn't have separated the projects. They should be one in the same.

Comment: Yes, I realized that too, but I want this to be the last option :(